# Starting asynchronous task via Spring TaskScheduler

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I need to execute a task at 7.05am but I am getting an error.
This is the Controller I created.

```
@Service("myCtr")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private TaskScheduler scheduler;

    @Async
    public void executeTaskT() {
        scheduler.schedule(new MyWorker(), 
                           new CronTrigger("5 7 * * *"));
        }
}
```

MyWorker is implementing Runnable simply this way:

```
    [...]
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doWork();
    }

    private void doWork() { [...]
```

My scheduler configuration file is imported by the web-application-config.xml:

```
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

<bean id="TaskScheduler"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler">
    <property name="waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
    <property name="poolSize" value="1000" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

The error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyCtr': Injection 
of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is   
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private  
org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler [...].MyController.scheduler; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type 
[org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which 
qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
[...]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private   
org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler [...].MyController.scheduler; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type 
[org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which 
qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
[...]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type 
[org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which 
qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Spring can't find your `TaskScheduler` bean.

With INFO logging, you should be able to find your bean definition in the log during initialization. If not, make sure your configuration file is effectively read by doing further tests.

For your precise need, you can also use the following:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 5 7 * * *")
    public void myMethod() { ... }

}
```

With this configuration:

```
<task:annotation-driven scheduler="myScheduler"/>
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="1000"/>
```

And assuming `MyService` is properly seen as a bean, using e.g. Component Scan.

Comment: I tried your solution and it works fine. However, I cannot use it, because the cron job is not fixed. The user can set it, so it has to be a variable, not in an annotation. On the other side, I figured out that the problem is in the configuration file: it was not "imported" by the context-file. Thanks.

Comment: I as well would want to all the user to assign this. Did you figure it out?